# How to concatenate multiple result rows of one row into one, based on FK

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am looking for a way to concatenate the result of the table into one row.

I have 4 tables;

Suppliers table

```
+--+----------------+----------------+
|id|name            |hook_name       |
+--+----------------+----------------+
|1 |724             |724             |
|2 |Air             |air             |
|3 |Akustik         |akustik         |     
|4 |Almira          |almira          |
+--+----------------+----------------+
```

Supplier Offices;
(`label` column represents pickup/dropoff string)

```
+---+-----------+----------+------------+
|id |supplier_id| zip_code | label      |  
+---+-----------+----------------+------+
|95 |24         |25325     |  344       | <- supplier_id 24 has office location 77,98 (label pickup)
|96 |24         |9535      |  93        | <- same. only label different (label dropoff) 
|97 |1          |2858      |  95        | 
|98 |1          |50285     |  954       | 
|99 |1          |10094     |  24        |
|100|1          |4353      |  59        |
+---+-----------+----------------+------+
```

OfficeLocations (Pivot table)

```
+------------------+-----------+
|supplier_office_id|location_id|
+------------------+-----------+
|95                |77         | <- location I want to concatenate `supplier_id = 24` (istanbul)
|96                |98         | <- location I want to concatenate `supplier_id = 24` (london)
|97                |77         | 
|98                |77         | 
+------------------+-----------+
```

Locations

```
+---------------+
|id |name       |
+---------------+
|77 |istanbul   |
|96 |berlin     |
|97 |newyork    |
|98 |london     |
+---------------+
```

I want to find the office for the given location information.
I haven't manage to create custom column about label.
If I want to access the office information of locations 1 and 2 I want to get something like this;

```
+---------------+------------+----------------+
| supplier_id | pickup_label | dropoff_label  |
+-------------+--------------+----------------+
| 95          | 344          | 93             |
+-------------+--------------+----------------+
```

I've been able to get this far right now with my Postgresl SQL.

```
SELECT supplier_offices.id,                   
       supplier_offices.supplier_id
FROM "supplier_offices"
         INNER JOIN suppliers on supplier_offices.supplier_id = suppliers.id
         INNER JOIN office_locations on supplier_offices.id = office_locations.supplier_office_id
AND ("office_locations"."location_id" IN (77, 98)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works if I understand what you mean. This code works if I understand what you mean. Of course for sql, but with a little change, I think it will work in Postgresl SQL as well

```
select supplier_offices.id as supplier_id, max(supplier_offices.label) as pickup_label, min(supplier_offices.label) as dropoff_label 
from supplier_offices 
inner join suppliers on supplier_offices.supplier_id = suppliers.id
inner join office_locations on supplier_offices.id = office_locations.supplier_office_id 
where office_locations.location_id in (77,98) 
group by supplier_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want some sort of aggregation.  It is entirely unclear hoe pickup locations are identified versus drop off.  But, something like this:

```
SELECT so.supplier_id,
       ARRAY_AGG(location_id) FILTER (WHERE so.label in (344)) as pickup,
       ARRAY_AGG(location_id) FILTER (WHERE so.label not in (344)) as dropoff
FROM "supplier_offices" so JOIN
     office_locations ol
     ON so.id = ol.supplier_office_id AND
        ol.location_id IN (77, 98)
GROUP BY so.supplier_id;
```